# Print p4 change/file info to .txt file or .csv

Tags: reporting, perforce

I am trying to figure out how to generate a report from Perforce.  Either GUI or command line is fine.

I have tried the below and that gives me everything I need with the exception of the list of files changed.

```
C:\Users\a148530>p4 changes -t -L -f @2015/03/30,@now
```

**Requirements**

- List all changelists in a given date range
- Include user, and files changed (with depot/path)

Essentially I am looking to export this view from the P4 GUI into .txt or .csv

[image]

Comment: You can make perforce follow your own output format string using the -F global option, as documented in this official post: https://community.perforce.com/s/article/15148

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to Perforce so I assume there's a better way, but this is what I do:

Parse out the list of changelists, then loop through it and for each changelist number:

1. Display the changelist info.
2. List the relevant files.

Here are some example commands for inside the loop for changelist number 12345:

```
p4 changes -t -l -m1 @12345
p4 files @=12345
```

Comment: You could use 'p4 describe -s 12345' to get both the change information and the list of files in a single command.

Answer (score -1):

You can save the output in any format by providing 
`> output.csv or output.txt`

e.g. `p4 changes -t -L -f @2015/03/30,@now > output.csv`

Comment: The output of this command is not CSV standard - as a CSV file, this is not very useful. You're right you can pipe the output into a TXT file and perhaps process it afterwards, but your answer is misleading in that it implies the output is CSV compatible.